# How to remove data validations?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to remove all data validations from a sheet, tried following but it does not get rid of them. Anyway to do this through apps script?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var accountSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Account A");
accountSheet.getRange(1,1,274,61).clear();
```

Comment: Looks like it is a known [bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5205&q=data%20validation&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner) with clear() although one can alternatively use clearDataValidations() which works.

Comment: I get:  `TypeError: Cannot find function clearDataValidations in object C2:D7.`

Comment: Ah I see, need to do something like:  `var validations_to_clear = active_sheet.getRange(2, 3, 6, 2);`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
accountSheet.getRange(1,1,274,61).setDataValidation(null)
```

That should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic answer to remove all data validations from the whole sheet (remove from all cells in sheet):

```
mySheet.getRange(1,1, mySheet.getMaxRows(), mySheet.getMaxColumns()).setDataValidation(null);
```

You could in theory use this less verbose version (might be faster because it affects a smaller range of cells):

```
mySheet.getDataRange().setDataValidation(null);
```

However, there may be empty cells outside the DataRange that do have validations and those validations will not be removed (they are outside the scope of DataRange, won't be selected by DataRange). Hence, you should use the first version I mentioned for more robust code: it selects all the cells in the sheet and removes validations.